# How to pass dynamic topic name to @KafkaListener(topics) from environment variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-el

I'm writing a Kafka consumer. I need to pass the environment variable topic name to `@KafkaListener(topics = ...)`. This is what I have tried so far:

```
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener; 
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

 @Service
 public class KafkaConsumer {

     @Autowired
     private EnvProperties envProperties;

     private final String topic = envProperties.getTopic();

     @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${envProperties.getTopic()}'}", groupId = "group_id")
     public void consume(String message) {
        logger.info("Consuming messages " +envProperties.getTopic());
     }
}
```

I'm getting an error at the line `topics = "#{'${envProperties.getTopic()}'}"`, the application fails to start.

How to set this topic name dynamically from the environment variable?

Answer (score 5):

Normally, you can't reference fields or properties from the bean in which the SpEL is declared. However, `@KafkaListener` has special syntax to support it.

[See the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#annotation-properties).

> Starting with version 2.1.2, the SpEL expressions support a special token `__listener` which is a pseudo bean name which represents the current bean instance within which this annotation exists.

So, if you add `public EnvProperties getEnvProperties()` to the class then something like

```
#{__listener.envProperties.topic}
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

In KafkaConsumer class, you need to make below changes :

```
@Autowired
public EnvProperties envProperties;

@KafkaListener(topics = "#{kafkaConsumer.envProperties.getTopic()}"
```

It worked for me.

Comment: What is the string "kafkaConsumer" from the "#{kafkaConsumer.envProperties.getTopic()}" ? Is the name of the class where the @KafkaListener is declared? or is a string keyword or where does it coming from?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to set topic as an environmental variable, you can pass the topic below

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{systemEnvironment['TOPIC']}")
```

Then you can set topic as below,

```
export TOPIC=mytopic
```