# How to set topic name in KafkaListener by code?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am writing the listener for kafka topic and using @kafkaListener annotation to do the same. Till now i hard-coded the topic name (topic1) and it was working fine.Here was a working code :-

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {

@Autowired
private KafkaProperties kafkaProps;


@Autowired
@Qualifier("CustomObjectMapper")
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@KafkaListener(topics = "topic1", containerFactory = "createPokafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void CreatePoListener(PurchaseOrder po, Acknowledgment ack)
    throws JsonProcessingException {

    LOG.info("Received message for po create from kafka topic {} is {}",
        kafkaProps.getOmsCreateTopicName(), objectMapper
            .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(po));

    ack.acknowledge();


}
```

}

Now, when i am trying to change the code to get the topic name from code, it is not working. Code which i tried to get the value from code after following this page in stack-overflow ([How to pass dynamic topic name to @kafkalistener(topics from environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54038928/how-to-pass-dynamic-topic-name-to-kafkalistenertopics-from-environment-variabl)) is :-

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {

@Autowired
private KafkaProperties kafkaProps;

public KafkaProperties getKafkaProps() {
    return kafkaProps;
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("CustomObjectMapper")
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@KafkaListener(topics = "#{__listener.kafkaProps.getOmsCreateTopicName()}", containerFactory = "omsCreatePokafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void CreatePoListener(PurchaseOrder po, Acknowledgment ack)
    throws JsonProcessingException {

    LOG.info("Received message for po create from kafka topic {} is {}",
        kafkaProps.getOmsCreateTopicName(), objectMapper
            .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(po));

    ack.acknowledge();


}
```

}

When i am trying to bring the server, it is throwing the error :-

**Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field '__listener' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?**

can someone help me here what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: What version are you using? That feature was added in 2.1.2.

Comment: @GaryRussell if you are asking about spring-kafka, we are using 1.1.3.RELEASE. let me increase the version and try it again

Comment: Yes I mean spring-kafka; the current release is 2.3.3. 1.1.x has not been supported for a long time.

Comment: @GaryRussell Since this is little old project and we are using spring 4.3.x version. And i guess 2.1.2 is supported by spring 5. I am getting no class def found error due to compatibility issue between Spring 4 and Spring-kafka-2.1.x. Is there any way i can achieve this in spring 4 keeping spring-kafka 1.1.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.1.x is no longer supported; if you can't upgrade beyond Spring Framework 4.3, you should upgrade to 1.3.10, which is the latest version for use with Spring 4.3; it has a much simpler and reliable threading model than 1.1.x, thanks to KIP-62.

While you can't use `__listener` with 1.3.x, you can use a SpEL expression to get the topic directly from the `KafkaProperties` bean:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{kafkaProps.omsCreateTopicName}" ...)
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. I made the suggested changes (upgrading 1.1.x to 1.3.10) and use SpEl as described above, but i am getting this error :-  "Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'kafkaProps' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?"

Comment: Given that you have `@Autowired
private KafkaProperties kafkaProps;` in your question, I assumed you have such a bean in your application context. If it has a different bean name, you must use the proper bean name in the expression.

Comment: I changed the variable name from kafkaProps to kafkaProperties and it started working. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In Consumer class, you need to make below changes :

```
@Autowired
public KafkaProperties kafkaProps;

@KafkaListener(topics = "#{kafkaConsumer.kafkaProps.getOmsCreateTopicName()}"
```

It worked for me.